# Webex on Citrix doesn't only shows physical webcam, but not NVIDIA Broadcast virtual cam (from host)

Tags: windows-10, webcam, citrix, virtual-webcam

Webex in the host system (Windows 10) can use the physical webcam or the virtual NVIDIA Broadcast version of it. The webex in the Citrix guest OS (also Windows 10) only shows the physical webcam. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: See this [link](https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX132764/information-on-webcams-in-citrix-virtual-apps-and-desktops) section 8.5 and try the included registry updates.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Do I have to add this to the registry on the host or citrix windows? What would be the app executable in my case? Citrix or webex?

Comment: Try it on the host, the application would be webex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A newer version of cisco webex citrix vdi solved it